# Convert from int to int32

Tags: c++, c, managed-c++

I have a bunch of int's in my c++ code that I need to change to int32's. Same with my bool's. What header do I need to include in order to use int32's and bool32's. Also how do I declare these once I make them. Am I able to just replace the int's with int32's?

For example:

```
int x;
```

Becomes

```
int32 x;
```

I am getting lots of errors when I try to change from int to int32. Here's a few:

`error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`

`error C2086: 'const int x' : redefinition`

Comment: right matthias, that's the whole issue here. I need the int's to be 32-bit even on 64-bit machines.

Comment: What is `bool32`? Such a type would be very sad. :C

Comment: And is it C, C++, or C++/CLI? Pick one, you're not programming all three.

Comment: @Graham: Then why is it tagged C and C++?

Comment: On Windows, `int` is 32-bit, period. Regardless of the cpu data or address width. If your code depends on Windows anyway, just keep `int`. It **will never change**. And I'm not sure why you think `int` getting larger would break your program anyway. If if does, your program already has major bugs.

Comment: @Graham:  If this is C++/CLI then you are prehaps referring to the .Net structure types `System.Int32` and `System.Boolean`, there is no Bool32, and Int32 has a capital I.  However neither type is directly supported in C++/CLI, they are underlying CLI types that are mapped to standard C++ built-in `int` and `bool`.  Either way this should not be tagged C++ if the question is C++/CLI specific, and should certainly not be tagged C at all.

Comment: What compiler lets you use int32? I have never seen that. I've seen int, int32_t and __int32_t, but never int32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows you should be able to use the built in type __int32.  I've never hear of a 32 bit bool, but you can just use typedef for that one.

Comment: I understand that, but when it is built in a 64-bit environment then `int` becomes 64-bit. I need it to be 32-bit no matter the environment. What Dan wrote is the solution.

Comment: @Graham - it doesn't, int is still 32-bits in x64 mode.

Comment: Well I think you are right, but the standard specifies only a minimum to represent int, just because it is now, even if it is currently on all ms windows systems, doesn't mean it's guaranteed to remain that way.  To write portable sustainable code where you need a specific size you really should use the provided types even if it's only to make it obvious that the code will break if you change the size.  FYI, boost also provides portable types which should work on all platforms <http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/boost/cstdint.hpp>

Comment: `int` is 32-bit on x64, for Windows, Linux and Mac OS X alike. However, `wchar_t` is 32-bit on Windows, but 64-bit on Linux/x64 and Mac/x64. Of course if portability is important, you can't make any such assumptions in general. For example, it is a very serious mistake to assume that each character in a wide string is 2 bytes long.

Answer (score 10):

```
<cstdint>
```

If your compiler supports it, will get you int32_t, the C99 fixed width integer type.

Never heard of no bool32 and I can't imagine what kind of sense it would even make.

Yes, you can just replace `int` with your type so long as your type remains fundamental and/or has a default constructor/non-implicit constructor...depending on use.

Comment: Because the ISO C++98 standard precedes ISO C99, a compiler supporting <stdint.h> may not have a corresponding <cstdint> C++ header (it is not a C++ standard header in C++98), so using <stdint.h> may be necessary.  If using VC++ it does not provide the header at all, but you can use this: http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h

Comment: @Clifford: You must be using an old version of VC++ because VC++ 2010 definitely provides the <cstdint> header.

Comment: @Balstfurnace: That's good to know, but that fact is not yet documented!: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7tkse1h.aspx, and certainly, neither stdint.h nor cstdint are provided in any version up-to and including 2008.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to have a `typedef` in place of the actual data type.

E.g.

```
typedef int my_int;
....
my_int var;
```

Becomes:

```
typedef int32 my_int;
....
my_int var;
```

That way, you could just change one line of code to change all instances of int to int32.

Comment: But that's too late if I understand the question correctly. He already has `int`s spread throughout the code.

Comment: He could easily find/replace " int " with " my_int ", then add the typedef.