# Is sizeof any type other than char guaranteed?

Tags: c++

I know that in C++ `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, but is it the only case or are there any other built-in types guaranteed to have exact size?

In particular is `sizeof(bool) == 1` or `sizeof(int) == 4` demanded by language or is it an implementation detail?

Comment: There are guaranteed minima, but no other guaranteed absolutes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does sizeof(int) vary across different operating systems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256695/why-does-sizeofint-vary-across-different-operating-systems)

Comment: Maybe better this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size is only guaranteed explicitly for `char`: `sizeof(char) == 1`. Implicitly this guarantee also applies to `signed char` and `unsigned char` as one of them is required to use the same representation as `char` and the other is bound by the conversion rules between `signed char` and `unsigned char` to use the same size.

Other than that there are only guarantees on the number if bits present in some types and a size relation between some types. Note, that `char` can have any number of bits equal or bigger than 8.

Comment: I would add as well the types int32, int64 etc. available via some C compilers. These should, as their name implies, guarantee a fixed bit length.

Comment: @JoshJ: I think you mean [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)

Answer (score 3):

The rules are strict enough that size of `signed char` and `unsigned char` must also be 1.

There is no other type for which the size is guaranteed--and I know of compilers that make `sizeof(bool)` a value larger than 1, and that make `sizeof(int)` a value other than 4.

Comment: But what about types like: `std::int32_t`, `std::int64_t` and `std::int128_t`. Those I'm sure are fixed sized data types. You should mention those.

Comment: @Brandon: Those may not even exist, and while their size in *bits* is guaranteed, the result of using `sizeof` on them isn't. For example, you could have 8-bit bytes, and sizeof(int32_t) == 4. Or you could have 16-bit bytes, and sizeof(int32_t) == 2. Or you could have 32-bit bytes, and sizeof(int32_t) == 1.

Comment: Wth.. God damn that is absolutely horrible.. Lol. An abomination. Lucky I've never come across a system like that so far..

Comment: adding this years later, but if you ever need to rely on these facts, using a `static_assert(sizeof(uint32) == 4, "")` will ensure that it must be correct for compilation to succeed

Comment: @AnneQuinn: `uint32_t` is really quite a different beast from `int`, with a lot more guarantees If it exists at all (which it almost always does) it's absolutely guaranteed to be 32 bits, so the only way `sizeof(uint32_t) != 4` would be a system that used a `char` that was larger than 8 bits. That's theoretically possible, but so far outside the mainstream that if it were true, I'd be somewhat surprised if it had a `uint32_t` at all. In any case, what you usually care about is size in bits, and that's guaranteed up-front with `uint32_t` (and `int32_t`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Types are not necessarily guaranteed to always have the same byte size across architectures. sizeof(X) is actually implemented by the compiler and outputs an integer (1,2,4,8, etc.) and is therefore not a function call. As a result, the output for a given type (e.g. int) will depend on the system for which your application was compiled. This is why you have to recompile an application for a different architecture.

That said, some types are always a particular size (e.g. int32).

See: [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be)

Comment: `int32` is not a type.

Comment: Some C++ compilers have explicit options for sizes like that don't they? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854886/convert-from-int-to-int32

Answer (score 2):

In theory, an (old C++) implementation (but probably not C++11) might have `sizeof` every scalar type (numerical, pointer, boolean) be 1. But I cannot name such an implementation (where `sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(double)`, `sizeof(long long)`, `sizeof(bool)`, `sizeof(void*)` are all 1).

You probably should use [`<cstdint>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) header if you care about data type sizes.

Also, code [portability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) can be tricky. You should care not only about integral data type size, but also about [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and operating system issues (standards like [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) should help). An aphorism says that *there is no software that is portable, only code that has been painfully ported*.

Comment: In the past the [Cray X-MP](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray_X-MP) had `sizeof(X) == 1` for all built-in types. It could only address 64 bit words. It predates the C++ standards, though. On the other hand, the rules on built-in types are inherited from C and there was a C compiler for the Cray X-MP.

Comment: I remember having coded a tiny bit on Cray-s (porting Ocaml interpreter to them). IIRC `sizeof(char*)` was different from `sizeof(int*)`